# Selecting elements within Google map using jQuery selectors

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

Ok so I am using infoBubble popup (http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html/) within Google Maps. It's like infoWindow but a little customizable one. I changed the library a bit and gave the bubble an ID (#infoBubble) hoping to manipulate it using jQuery. But it seems I am not able to select it. The DIV that contains the map can be selected using jQuery but no element within it can be selected. Can anyone help me with this?

I am trying to access the infoBubble div from within the usual $(document).ready(function() {}

UPDATE: After learning from geocodezip's reply that div created in the infoBubble is not part of the DOM, I added a listener event like so:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infoBubble, "domready", function( { 
    $j('#infoBubble').click(function(){alert('bubble clicked');}); 
});
```

Now it's getting somewhere. This works. Although I am experiencing problems because there are many infoBubble popups, I will edit this question if I face some trouble. As of now, this works.

Comment: When are you trying to access the div in the infoBubble?  Is it attached to the DOM and visible?

Comment: Hi geocodezip, I updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The div created in the infoBubble is not part of the DOM until the infoWindow is opened and rendered.  Use the [infoWindow domready event](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow) to access it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I added the listener, domready event for infoBubble but still can't get the selectors working.

Comment: This worked. However, i am facing a couple of issues because I am opening multiple infoBubbles within a loop, but I hope to solve them out.

Comment: If you are opening infoBubbles in a loop, look at [this example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3.html) which uses function closure (a createMarkers function).  The example uses infoWindows, but the concept applies to infoBubbles.